# How to pass an argument to a method using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to pass an argument to a method named checkMessages. checkMessages method is called in two places one call it with 1 argument and the other calls it with 2 arguments.

below is the code,

```
const checkMessages = (messages, isActive) => {
    cy.logout();
    changeUser(someuser);

    if (isActive) {
        cy.getByTestId('toggle').click();
        messages.forEach(message =>
            cy.get('textarea[id="description"]').type(message)
        );
    }

    messages.forEach(message =>
        cy.getTableRow('Description', message)
    );
}

checkMessages([
    `some message ${item1.name}were added`,
    `some message ${item2.name} were added`,
]); // one method call with one argument

checkMessages([
    `some message ${item1.name}were added`,
], isActive=true); // second method call with two arguments
//error with this function call
```

Now the problem is when the checkMessages method is called with 2 arguments call it throws error "isActive is not defined"

how do i pass this argument to checkMessages method. how should the function call be with this argument.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: ``checkMessages([
    `some message ${item1.name}were added`,
], true);`` You don't name `messages`, so there's no need to name `isActive`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `isActive == true`? That would cause this error, not the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing isActive = true in your example. the isActive is property is not defined in the calling scope, hence throwing an error while calling the `checkMessages` function.

you can fix it by call the function by just passing the boolean true.

```
checkMessages([
 `some message ${item1.name}were added`,
], true);
```

Comment: `isActive = true` is not causing any errors, it's just not necessary. That part works perfectly fine as it was.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript does not have keyword arguments. So in your line

```js
checkMessages([
    `some message ${item1.name}were added`,
], isActive=true);
```

you are trying to specify `isActive` as a keyword. Eslint thinks that you are trying to access a variable called `isActive`, which does not exist in the scope of the function caller. However, the code should still work because the `isActive=true` part will assign `isActive` as a global variable here.

If you want to use a similar thing to keywords, you can create a function that takes an object and use destructing assignment, like this

```js
const checkMessages = (messages, {isActive}) => {
    // ...
};
```

and then you can call it like this

```js
checkMessages('...', {isActive: true});
```

That will give you a similar effect, but it's still not technically the same thing as keyword arguments.

Comment: It's not accessing the variable, it's assigning it. So why would that cause an error?

Comment: Assigning the variable should just create a global variable and pass the value to the function.

Comment: Variables are created using `var`, `const`, and `let`. None of those words are present here.

Comment: If you don't declare a variable, it automatically becomes a global variable when you assign to it.

Comment: @nullromo - false. `isActive=true` is a perfectly valid variable definition. Those keywords only change the scope. without them the variable is global.